# фильтрация списка по булевым значениям

Tags: python, list, bool

Я знаю, что в R есть такой трюк, когда имеется список `s=[1,2,3,4]` и к нему добавляя список из булевых значений, можно получить нужные элементы. Например, `s=[1,2,3,4][True,False,False,True]` выдаст результат `[1,4]`. Можно ли сделать так в питоне с помощью встроенных функций, не прибегая к пандас и др библиотекам?

Answer (score 3):

Если не считать `itertools` внешней библиотекой (и не стоит ее считать таковой)

```py
>>> list(itertools.compress([1,2,3,4], [True,False,False,True]))
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

можно, например, так:

```
s = [1,2,3,4]
b = [True,False,False,True]
res = [x[0] for x in zip(s,b) if x[1]]
print(res)
```

> [1, 4]

или так:

```
s = [1,2,3,4]
b = [True,False,False,True]
res = [s[i] for i, e in enumerate(b) if e]
print(res)
```

> [1, 4]

Comment: Спасибо, я думаю, 2 вариант даже предпочтительнее по скорости работы. А вообще, я уже понял, что для моей задачи просто подошла бы функция filter() и lambda.